# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'c' in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to run a very simple query using SQLAlchemy on some data in a MariaDB database. It is an `EXCEPT` query that I am looking for, to get the results that are in my first selection but not in the second. This is what that looks like,

```
sqlalchemy.except_(self.session.query(Entities).all(), self.session.query(EntitiesBckp).all())
```

However, I keep getting this error,

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'c'
```

What exactly is the problem here?

Note: I can display the models on request, but I do not think it is necessary. Both of the models used in this query (`Entities` and `EntitiesBckp`) have exactly the same structure.

Comment: `.all()` dumps query results into `list`s; does it work if you remove the `.all()`s from both subqueries?

Comment: Yes, the query was executed and I got a `CompoundSelect` object. How can I extract the data from this?

Comment: I think you should be able to call `.all()` on that object?

Comment: Nope, it does not work. `AttributeError: 'CompoundSelect' object has no attribute 'all'`

Comment: @snakecharmerb `engine.execute(sqlalchemy.except_(session.query(Entities), session.query(EntitiesBckp))).fetchall()` works for me.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Why don't you add this as an answer? This is the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are invoking `sqlalchemy.except_` which is part of the symbolic statements for query building (judging from the `__init__.py` of sqlalchemy). If converted to SQL it would most likely print as `EXCEPT`, and it lacks the `SELECT ...` portion of a full query, i.e. `EXCEPT SELECT FROM ... SELECT FROM ...`

If we refer to [SQL Alchemy docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/queryguide.html?highlight=union#selecting-entities-from-unions-and-other-set-operations) we see that a second variety of `except_` exists, and that is a function on a query object. Working with the query `except_` allows you to chain from one query into the next: `self.session.query(Entities).except_(self.session.query(EntitiesBckp)).all()`

Working with the statement `except_` gives you a symbolic statement that must be executed e.g. `session.execute(except_statement).all()`

In other words, in the question you've wrapped two query objects in a statement operation, when you should be wrapping your statement objects in a query.

Also note that sqlalchemy 1.4+ deprecates the session.query() approach in favour of newer syntax like `session.execute(except_(select(Entities), select(EntitiesBckp)))`